# Pandas set_index creates undesired new row -- how do I just do the obvious thing?

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to set the index of a dataframe from one of the columns in my dataframe. The old index of this dataframe is essentially meaningless.

[image]

But when I use `set_index(['Name'])` I add a new column, which isn't the behavior I want. I can't find a way around this:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is presentation only.  `pandas` preserves the column name in the name attribute of the new minted index.  To differentiate the name of the index as opposed to column headers, pandas places that extra row spacer to visually set it apart.

If you don't want it there, you can rename the index

```
labels.set_index('Name').rename_axis(None)
```

Comment: @AlexLenail that is the name of the `columns` index.  That can be solved with `.rename_axis(None, axis=1)`

Answer (score 3):

"Name" is the name of the index.  To get rid of this you can:

```
labels.index.name = None
```

Comment: Thanks Scott! I wish I could accept two answers but SO only lets me pick one =(

Answer (score 0):

If you have been trying to print to HTML using df.to_html and getting 2 headers then this seems to work

```
dfallactionsclean.to_html(index=False...
```